# Bundled product - Specify items

Tags: magento-1.9, bundled-product

I am looking to create a bundled product that includes 3 beers. The user should be able to specify, which of our 10 different beers they want to include in the bundled product. They should be able to choose 3 different beers or 3 of the same beer. Is it possible to create this from a default Magento installation and if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

Hm try to set up new bundle product and there set three options (if you want customer to choose always three - then set all options as `required`). Every option should contain all ten kinds of beer to choose from. Then your customer should have possibility to mix set of three beers from provided ones. Of course this can be done from adminhtml or programatically.